# How to Count advanced query rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to count this query rows . please help

```
SELECT 
    CrmDesk.Request.*  
FROM            
    CrmDesk.Request 
INNER JOIN  
    CrmDesk.Customer ON CrmDesk.Request.CustomerId = CrmDesk.Customer.Id   
WHERE
    (CrmDesk.Customer.GroupeId = '84b4ea32-b39b-49d3-bb24-35fd933fc594')
    AND (RequestStatus != 4)
    AND CrmDesk.Request.CustomerId IS NOT NULL 
    AND RequestStatus != 4 

UNION 

SELECT 
    CrmDesk.Request.* 
FROM   
    CrmDesk.Customer 
INNER JOIN 
    CrmDesk.CustomerOrder ON CrmDesk.Customer.Id = CrmDesk.CustomerOrder.CustomerId 
INNER JOIN 
    CrmDesk.Request ON CrmDesk.CustomerOrder.Id = CrmDesk.Request.OrderId    
WHERE
    (CrmDesk.Customer.GroupeId = '84b4ea32-b39b-49d3-bb24-35fd933fc594')
    AND (RequestStatus != 4) 

UNION

SELECT
    * 
FROM
    [CrmDesk].[Request]  
WHERE
    UserFrom IS NOT NULL
    AND RequestStatus != 4 
    AND OwnerId IS NOT NULL
    AND UserFrom IN (SELECT Id FROM [Karbazi].[User] 
                     WHERE Id = '84b4ea32-b39b-49d3-bb24-35fd933fc594' 
                       AND RequestStatus != 4 

                     UNION

                     SELECT Id FROM [Karbazi].[User] 
                     WHERE ParentUserId = '84b4ea32-b39b-49d3-bb24-35fd933fc594') 
     OR  OwnerId IN (SELECT UserId 
                     FROM [CrmDesk].[Customer] 
                     WHERE groupeId = '84b4ea32-39b-49d3-bb24- 35fd933fc594') 
    AND UserFrom IS NOT NULL
    AND RequestStatus != 4 

UNION

SELECT * 
FROM [CrmDesk].[Request] 
WHERE UserToDo IN (SELECT id 
                   FROM [Karbazi].[User] 
                   WHERE ParentUserId='84b4ea32-b39b-49d3-bb24-35fd933fc594'  
                      OR id ='84b4ea32-b39b-49d3-bb24-35fd933fc594' ) 
  AND RequestStatus != 4
```

Comment: Your tables only contain one column? Otherwise your unions aren't going to work.

Comment: what mean doesnt work? Show us the error.    Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
   
   And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach would be this

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
  --put your query here
) AS tbl
```